# Unexpected behavior in RxJava with observables constructed using AtomicIntegers

Tags: rx-java, atomic, system.reactive

Here's the test case:

```java
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class MainTest {
   public static AtomicInteger s1Id = new AtomicInteger(1);
   public static AtomicInteger s2Id = new AtomicInteger(1);
   public static int s1Id() {return s1Id.getAndIncrement();}
   public static int s2Id() {return s2Id.getAndIncrement();}
   public static class S1 {
       public int idS1;
       public S1() {
           idS1 = s1Id();
       }
    }
    public static class S2 {
        public int idS1;
        public int idS2;
        public S2(int idS1) {
            this.idS1 = idS1;
            idS2 = s2Id();
        }
    }
    public static Observable<Long> clock = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Observable<S1> s1Observable = clock.filter(l->l<1).map(l->(new S1()));
        s1Observable.subscribe(s1->System.out.println("S1: "+s1.idS1));
        Observable<S2> s2Observable = s1Observable.map(s1->new S2(s1.idS1));
        s2Observable.subscribe(s2->System.out.println("S2: idS1: "+s2.idS1 + " idS2: " + s2.idS2));
        try{Thread.sleep(100000);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}`
```

The output I usually get:
S1: 1
S2: idS1: 2 idS2: 1

(Though I think I also saw:
S1: 2
S2: idS1: 1 idS2: 1)

In any case since the value of s1.idS1 is being used to construct S2 I would expect the values
of idS1 to be the same.  The clock is necessary to provoke the problem.
What concurrency issue am I not getting?

I've reduced my original problem to this minimal case.

Comment: Not clear what you trying to achieve here. You have two instantiations of the clock so s1Id gets two increments. You may see is depending on which observable gets there first. There are no global order guarantees for timed actions; you'd need a single threaded scheduler for that everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten about the distinction between hot and cold observables.  Since s1Observable is cold it will be rerun in the expression for s2observable and hence pick up a different value for the id. (On the other hand if it had been hot it wouldn't have generated anything.)

Comment: There's no silly questions. It is so disrespectful.